# BottomAppBar and BottomNavigationView with FloatingActionButton UI is messed up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottomappbar, android-bottom-nav-view

I have added *`BottomAppBar` and `BottomNavigationView` with `FloatingActionButton`* inside *`ConstraintLayout`* but the white strip is showing at bottom of the screen in the entire application. On this screen, a Navigation drawer is added using `Drawerlaout`, and `Framelayout` is used for that. Now it is difficult to manage all these components.

So, please check the below code and help me to sort this UI issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/header_layout" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_constraint"></FrameLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/White"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_coordinator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/White">

                <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/lighter_gray"
                    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
                    app:fabCradleMargin="7dp"
                    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="7dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/navigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp"
                    app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color"
                    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_color"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab_options"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:fabSize="auto"
                    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add" />

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/background_gray"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/background_gray"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am adding a screenshot of the UI issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove this padding, but you can solve this by adding an elevation to the `BottomAppBar`.

Doing that, you could encounter artifacts at right and left of the `BottomNavigationView`, to fix this Add `0dp` Elevation to the `BottomNavigationView`.

**Extra Notes:**

- Remove the constraints from the `BottomNavigationView` as it is not
  wrapped in a `ConstraintLayout`
- You can drop the `ConstraintLayout` that wraps the `CoordinatorLayout`,
  as it's an extra `ViewGroup` that has no need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/header_layout" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout_constraint"></FrameLayout>


        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_coordinator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/lighter_gray"
                app:elevation="10dp"
                app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
                app:fabCradleMargin="7dp"
                app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="7dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_color"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_options"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:fabSize="auto"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/background_gray"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/background_gray"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```